# React /Formik - How to disable autofocus from the first field in a Formik form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form build with formik, it is set in a modal. When I open the modal the first field is always focused. This is the form:

```
   <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit} enableReinitialize>
      {({  isValid}) => (
        <Form>
          <FlexRow>
            <FlexColumn className="mr-4 w-36">
              <FormikDate
                icon={<IconFa icon={calendarAlt} />}
                label={i18next.t('timeWindow.customDateLabel')}
                name="date"
                disabledDate={isDayInThePast}
                validate={(value: string) => formikIsValidYYYYMMDDDate(value, 'Date not valid')}
              />
            </FlexColumn>
            <FlexColumn className="mr-4 w-36">
              <FormikTime
                name="timeFrom"
                label={i18next.t('btimeWindow.timeFrom')}
                icon={<IconFa icon={clock} />}
                validate={(value: string) => formikValidationRequired(value, i18next.t('application.required'))}
              />
            </FlexColumn>
            <FlexColumn className="mr-4 w-36">
              <FormikTime
                type="time"
                name="timeTo"
                label={i18next.t('timeWindow.timeTo')}
                icon={<Icon icon={clock} />}
                validate={(value: string) => formikValidationRequired(value, i18next.t('application.required'))}
              />
            </FlexColumn>
          </FlexRow>
          <hr className="w-full mt-8    border-t border-gray-300 border-0 border-solid" />
          <FlexRow justifyContent="end" gap="8">
            <ButtonBase variant="secondary" onClick={toggleCustomTimeView} type="button">
              {i18next.t('button.cancel')}
            </ButtonBase>
            <ButtonBase
              variant="primary"
              type="submit"
              disabled={!isValid}
            >
              {i18next.t('timeWindow.timeSlot')}
            </ButtonBase>
          </FlexRow>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

How can I avoid having first field focused?

Since in my case first field is a `DatePicker` which then opens its own modal with calendar and I don't want it to be open without clicking on the field first.

Comment: I think that this in not the formik issue. I have never encountered a similar issue with this library. Maybe it's caused by the datePicker component? Have You checked that? If it's possible it'd be much easier to help with some basic example prepared on codesandbox

Comment: Could the focus be set by the modal component? Are you using a 3rd party lib?

Comment: @Ludwig Can you share an example on codesandbox plz?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know... but I can try to suggest a couple of attempts.

**1st attempt:** `tabIndex`

It seems that Formik does not support the `tabIndex` attribute: just nest your *Formik fileds* in a `<div>` (without any margin, border and padding) with the proper `tabIndex`.

```
            <FlexColumn className="mr-4 w-36">
              <div tabIndex="3">
                <FormikDate
                  icon={<IconFa icon={calendarAlt} />}
                  label={i18next.t('timeWindow.customDateLabel')}
                  name="date"
                  disabledDate={isDayInThePast}
                  validate={(value: string) => ...}
                />
              </div>
            </FlexColumn>
```

A possible attempt to completely avoid a field to be focused could be to add an empty `<div tabIndex="0">` inside the `<Formik>` - before any form field - and setting `tabIndex` greather than `0` for all other fields.

**2nd attempt: throug code**

```
useEffect(() => document.activeElement.blur(), []);
```